# Partitioning in convex problem (variables in two subsets)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the following problem from textbook `Convex Optimization Algorithm p.10`:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&{\text{min}}
& & F(x)+G(y)\\
& \text{s.t.} & &  x \in \mathcal{X},\ \ y \in \mathcal{Y} \\
& & &  Ax+By=c \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

By partitioning, it can be written as

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&{\text{min}}
& & F(X) +\underset{By=c-Ax,\ \ y\in \mathcal{Y}}{\text{inf}} G(y)\\
& \text{s.t.} & &  x \in \mathcal{X} \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

It seems this trick just transform the original problem to a new one with only one variable $x$. The condition is that the oprinal problem should be seperable.

There are two constraints, one is $y \in \mathcal{Y}$ and a equality constraint. **Can we say more about the second problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The go-to method for attacking your problem is the ADMM (Alternating Directions Method of Multipliers).

Your can learn ADMM from [Stephen Boyd's ADMM Page](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html). For a more in-depth theory, see

- Eckstein, J., Bertsekas, D.P.: On the Douglas-Rachford splitting method and the proximal point algorithm for maximal monotone operators. Mathematical Programming 55 (1992)
- Glowinski, R., Marroco, A.: Sur l’approximation, par ́elements finis d’ordre un, et la resolution, par p ́enalisation-dualit ́e d’une classe de problemes de Dirichlet non lin ́eaires. ESAIM: Mathe- matical Modelling and Numerical Analysis-Modélisation Mathématique et Analyse Numérique 9 (1975)
- Gabay, D., Mercier, B.: A dual algorithm for the solution of nonlinear variational problems via finite element approximation. Computers & Mathematics with Applications 2 (1976)

Hope this helps.